# Copying a std::tuple

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I was trying to assign some values to a class derived from std::tuple. 
The first thing I thought of, was to use `make_tuple` and then copy it with the `operator=`, but that didn't work.

If I  manually assigned the single values of the tuple instead, there was no problem.

So I've written a little piece of code, extracting it from the project, to test specifically this single thing:

```
#include <tuple>
template <class idtype>
class Userdata: public std::tuple<idtype, WideString, int>
{
  public:
  /* compile error
  void assign1(const idtype& id, const WideString& name, const int lvl)
  {
    (*this)=std::make_tuple(id, name, lvl);
  }
  */
  void assign2(const idtype& id, const WideString& name, const int lvl)
  {
    (std::tuple<idtype, WideString, int>)(*this)=std::make_tuple(id, name,  lvl);
  }
  void assign3(const idtype& id, const WideString& name, const int lvl)
  {
    std::get<0>(*this)=id;
    std::get<1>(*this)=name;
    std::get<2>(*this)=lvl;
  }
  void print(const WideString& testname) const
  {
    std::cout << testname << ": " << std::get<0>(*this) << " " << std::get<1>(*this) << " " << std::get<2>(*this) << std::endl;
  }

  Userdata()
  {
  }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Userdata<int> test;
  /*
  test.assign1("assign1", 1, "test1", 1);
  test.print();
  */
  test.assign2(2, "test2", 2);
  test.print("assign2");
  test.assign3(3, "test3", 3);
  test.print("assign3");
}
```

The results are

```
assign2: 0  0 
assign3: 3 test3 3
```

With only `assign3` giving the expected result.
So, while I can easily use the `assign3` function, I'm still wondering what is wrong with `assign2`.

Comment: Btw, are you sure you want inheritance here, instead of simple composition?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was going to suggest the same, but thought maybe there was something I wasn't grasping.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks for the reply below. Yes, I wanted inheritance because other function expect to interact with a tuple there, so it seemed the easiest path to follow. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(std::tuple<idtype, WideString, int>)(*this)
```

creates a new temporary that you then assign to. Cast to reference instead:

```
(std::tuple<idtype, WideString, int>&)(*this)=std::make_tuple(id, name,  lvl);
```